# UV Unwrap: Unwrap Mesh to fixed pixel per unit

Tags: texturing, uv, scale

I'm building a game asset and want to keep an eye on equal mapping aspect ratio.

So my question is:
how can I unwrap my object so that blender keeps a fixed ratio of *1 unit = 20px* in the UV map. It doesn't matter if the UV mesh extends the UV texture, I will rearrange and scale manually.

Google or Stack Exchange didn't give me a good answer.

Comment: Check out the Texel Density tool in the [TexTools](http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/) addon.

Comment: Thx David, TexTools is the solution. It offers an option to scale the UV Islands to a desired Pixel per unit size. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[David's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103318/uv-unwrap-unwrap-mesh-to-fixed-pixel-per-unit#comment184375_103318) was the answer I was looking for.

[TexTools](https://github.com/SavMartin/TexTools-Blender/releases) is perfect for that. While in UV Editing mode it allows you to calculate the actual Texel-per-Unit-Ratio. You can also set a specific texel density manually which scales the UV islands to that specific size.
It also offers many more options for UV editing.

A smaller version only to change the texel density ist the [Texel Density Checker](https://gumroad.com/l/CEIOR) on Gumroad.

Both tools work together without interfering each other.

Comment: Do you mind *explaining in detail* why?

Answer (score 2):

**1. Load texture with desired size**

First note that UV coordinates are relative to the width and height of the loaded texture. So in order to define your UVs in pixel-units especially if your texture isn't square you should first load the image-texture and use the option "correct aspect" that some unwrapping methods have.

If no image is selected, blender will assume 256x256.

**2. Evaluate Stretching**

To get an even pixel-per-blenderunit ratio across the asset your unwrap should have no stretching in angle and area. No stretch means if you print the UVs on paper and cut out you should be able to build the 3d modell out of it.

To evaluate stretching activate Display->stretch:

[image: Display stretch in Blender UV Editor]

Note the concave/convex parts of the model in the screenshot: More seams need to be added or a method like "Smart UV Project" could be used. In addition the function "minimize stretch" can optimize the result.

**3. Find out the pixel-per-blenderunit ratio**

There might be other methods/addons for this but it's not so hard to calculate by hand:

1. Messure the length of an edge in 3d viewport by calculating the distance between the two vertices: 
   $d_{3D} =
      \sqrt{(x_{v1}-x_{v2})^2+(y_{v1}-y_{v2})^2+(z_{v1}-z_{v2})^2}$
2. Messure the length of the same edge in UV-Map by calculating the distance of the two UV-vertices:
   $d_{UV} =
      \sqrt{(x_{v1}-x_{v2})^2+(y_{v1}-y_{v2})^2}$
3. Calculate the pixel-per-blenderunit ratio with:
   $currentratio = {d_{UV} \over d_{3D}}$

In a UV without stretching this ratio should be the same for every edge.

**4. Scale UV**

Having found out the current px/bu ratio you can scale your UV by a factor s to get the desired ratio:

$currentratio \cdot s = desiredratio$

This leads to:

$s = {desiredratio \over currentratio}$.

**Alternatives to UV**

Also have a look at the [other texture coordinate methods in blender](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-input-encyclopedia) although I'm not sure wether you can use them in a game.

Comment: One very convenient way to find distance with vectors is `(v1.co - v2.co).length`  (where `v1` is a vertex, and `v1.co` its vector coordinate)  Vector math pretty much removes the need to use Euclidean distance formula.